# magento 2 : show all attributes after filters in layered navigation

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, filter

I want to show all attributes and their options after filter applied.

so what I want is Filter should remain same it is after filter applied.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: @themanwhoknowstheman I used this extension https://github.com/NikZh/magento2-multiple-layered-navigation and hack some of the classes according to my requirement